# Consistency of a strange (choice-wise) set of reals, pt. 2

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, gn.general-topology, forcing, axiom-of-choice

This is a follow-up on [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428346/consistency-of-a-strange-choice-wise-set-of-reals) question. Consider a set $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that

1. $X$ is *not* separable wrt its subspace topology
2. Every countable family of non-empty pairwise disjoint subsets of $X$ has a choice function

In a model containing such a set $\text{AC}_\omega(X)$ (choice for countable families of non-empty subsets of $X$) would of course fail, but not that critically.
In particular, the way I've seen to prove the consistency of $\neg \text{AC}_\omega (\mathbb{R})$ via symmetric extensions is to add a countable family of pairwise disjoint set of reals and then showing it has no choice function in the symmetric submodel. In other words we usually add a set of reals for which 2. does not hold. Indeed the examples given in the answers of the linked question fail to satify this property.

I've tried to think on how to prove the consistency of such a set via a symmetric extension approach, but the ideas I've had are complicated and they all share the same (maybe wrong) intuition that the iteration of Cohen' forcing needs to be involved, but this would bring the argument away from the more "standard" reasonings I've seen when dealing with symmetric extension, where usually forcing' products are used.

Do you have any idea?
Thanks!